# How to add a search functionality to a Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I've been asked to add search functionality to a Wordpress theme that has neither search.php page, is this possible? Is it possible using plugins?

The theme is this:
http://themeforest.net/item/heal-responsive-medical-wordpress-theme/3127829?sso?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=raybreaker

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like david.binda said, Wordpress already have this feature.

But it is possible that this template uses WP_Query. In this case, you could add the "s" parameter in this WP_Query:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 's=keyword' );
```

[WP_Query Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score 0):

Search capability is not in theme. It is inside your WordPress installation and already works. Try to enter your home url with ?s=some+text param.

To enable theme to display search results in different way than normal archive page, it is easy as copying archive.php and renaming it to **search.php** plus you'll probably wont to modify it slightly (maybe adding h1 with [the_search_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_search_query) function ). Next, you'll have to create **searchform.php** inside your theme. You can use this code from codex for your file

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Plus, you have to either insert search plugin into widgetized sidebar or add search form somewhere else into your theme (probably header.php). You can benefit from this [get_search_form function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form)